# No instance of function template "***" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a following function

```
template <typename T>
static __global__ void ExtractSpherical_kernel(T *__restrict__ spherical)
{...}
```

which gets called based on a condition if `pixel` size is 8 or 16. The original calls looks:

```
if(pixels == 8)
  ExtractSpherical_kernel<<<12, 1024, 4096, ec.stream>>>((hdr_8_t*)ins.Get(ec));
else
  ExtractSpherical_kernel<<<12, 1024, 4096, ec.stream>>>((hdr_16_t*)ins.Get(ec));
```

I tried to make it concise by following (as there are a long list of variables passed in the function which I removed for simplicity here).

```
auto ins_data_type = (pixels == 8) ? (hdr_8_t*)ins.Get(ec) : (hdr_16_t*)ins.Get(ec);
ExtractSpherical_kernel<<<12, 1024, 4096, ec.stream>>>(ins_data_type);
```

However I get following error:

```
/home/sam/Docs/hello.cu(429): error: operand types are incompatible ("hdr_8_t *" and "hdr_16_t *")

/home/sam/Docs/hello.cu(431): error: no instance of function template "ExtractSpherical_kernel" matches the argument list
```

what am I missing?

Comment: And please also tag `cuda` because that's not standard-C++ either.

Comment: Is `pixels` really a value that you find out in runtime?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, it is runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto ins_data_type = (pixels == 8) ? (hdr_8_t*)ins.Get(ec) : (hdr_16_t*)ins.Get(ec);
```

The type of the variable or expression is always fixed at compile-time and can't depend on the value of the expression or initializer. You are trying here to change the type of `ins_data_type` dependent on the runtime value of `pixels`. That's fundamentally not possible.

Comment: Is this a valid approach? from chatgpt: https://pastebin.com/k0JisVBr

Comment: @SKPS ChatGPT doesn't know how to code. It will just mash words together in a manner that seems probable.

Comment: @SKPS It is non-sense as always. (Though technically it _is_ correct that you won't get the specific type error anymore. However it will either fail somewhere deeper down or even worse have UB instead.)

Comment: @SKPS If `pixels` has a value that you know already at compiletime, you can use that to your advantage with `if constexpr (pixels == 8) { ... } else { ... }`